# Can one "go against" an objection?

Tags: word-choice

There were a few examples on google, but very limited and mostly blogs and the like.  I'm thinking that words like "ignore" tend to be used with "objections."  But is there a word like "defy" that can be used with "objections"?  "Go against" is the best I can think of, but it really just doesn't sound quite right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [**brush aside**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brush+aside), [**wave aside**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/wave-sth-aside), and  [**dismiss**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismiss) [an objection].

> [brush aside](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brushed+aside+the+objection%2Cwaved+aside+the+objection&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrushed%20aside%20the%20objection%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwaved%20aside%20the%20objection%3B%2Cc0): to dismiss without consideration; disregard
>
> wave aside: to refuse to consider what something says
>
> dismiss: to reject serious consideration of

Answer (score 1):

More active than *ignore* would be *disregard*.  You can also *shrug off* objections.

Answer (score 0):

The term procatalepsis **defies by anticipation** (knowing the likely argument before rebuttal), and negates any objection:

> **[Procatalepsis](http://www.course-notes.org/English/Rheotical_Devices/Procatalepsis)**  by anticipating an objection and answering it, permits an argument to continue moving forward while taking into
>   account points or reasons opposing either the train of thought or its
>   final conclusions.

In legal speak, an objection to an objection, or a rebuttal to a rebuttal is a surrebutter

> **[Surrebuttal](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/3299805)**: In an adversarial process, for instance a court proceeding, a surrebuttal is a response to the opposing party's
>   rebuttal; in essence it is a rebuttal to a rebuttal.